# Different number of predictions than expecting in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict

I'm anticipating that I'm missing something glaringly obvious here.

I'm trying to build a demonstration of overfitting. I've got a quadratic generating function from which I've drawn 20 samples, and I now want to fit polynomial linear models of increasing degree to the sampled data.

For some reason, regardless which model I use, every time I run `predict` I get N predictions back, where N is the number of records used to train my model.

```
set.seed(123)
N=20
xv = seq(1,5,length.out=1e4)
x=sample(xv,N)
gen=function(v){v^2 + 2*rnorm(length(v))}
y=gen(x)
df = data.frame(x,y)

# convenience function for building formulas for polynomial regression
build_formula = function(N){ 
  fpart = paste(lapply(2:N, function(i) {paste('+ poly(x,',i,',raw=T)')}  ), collapse="")
  paste('y~x',fpart)
}
## Example:
## build_formula(4)="y~x + poly(x, 2 ,raw=T)+ poly(x, 3 ,raw=T)+ poly(x, 4 ,raw=T)"



model = lm(build_formula(10), data=df)
predict(model, data=xv) # returns 20 values instead of 1000
predict(model, data=1)  # even *this* spits out 20 results. WTF?
```

This behavior is present regardless of the degree of polynomial in the formula, including the trivial case `'y~x'`:

```
formulas = sapply(c(2,10,20), build_formula)
formulas = c('y~x', formulas)
pred = lapply(formulas
              ,function(f){
                predict(
                  lm(f, data=df)
                  ,data=xv)
              })

lapply(pred, length) # 4 x 20 predictions, expecting 4 x 1000

# unsuccessful sanity check
m1 = lm('y~x', data=df)
predict(m1,data=xv)
```

This is driving me insane. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `predict` is `newdata`, not `data`.

Also, you don't need multiple calls to `poly` in your model formula; `poly(N)` will be collinear with `poly(N-1)` and all the others.

Also^2, to generate a sequence of predictions using `xv`, you have to put it in a data frame with the appropriate name: `data.frame(x=xv)`.

Comment: You're a beautiful person. Yeah, I got warnings when I changed to `newdata`, but I just fixed them with `newdata=list(x=x)` which is basically the same thing. Figured it was something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Actually `predict(m1)` would be the same as `predict(m1, newdata=list(x=x))`

Comment: David, I think he's beautiful too :).

Comment: @DWin that's good to know, but that's not what I'm trying to do. OH, I see why you brought that up, I meant that I used `list(x=xv)`. That was a typo above. My mistake.